# undefined method in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am fairly new to Rails, and I am following an online tutorial that has you build a book review app. Everything seems to work except for when I submit a review. When I do, I get this error:

```
undefined method `book_id=' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is my reviews controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_book 

def new
    @review = Review.new
end

def create
    @reivew = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.book_id = @book.id
    @review.user_id = @current_user.id
    if @review.save
        redirect_to book_path(@book)
    else
        render "new"
    end
end




private 

    def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment)
    end


    def find_book
        @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    end
end
```

Here is my Review model:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :book
belongs_to :user

end
```

Here is my Book model:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category 
has_many :reviews


has_attached_file :book_img, styles: { book_index: "250x350>", book_show:     "325x475>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :book_img, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

I feel like I've been reading help forums for the past two hours. I'm stuck. Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in `review` in your `create` action.

Change the following line

```
@reivew = Review.new(review_params)
```

to

```
@review = Review.new(review_params)
```

The reason for the error is that `@review` is `nil` and you can't call the method `book_id` on a `nil` object.

Comment: Thank you! It now has a problem with this line: 
    @review.user_id = @current_user.id

It says:
    undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Its because `@current_user` is nil. Where do you set the `@current_user` variable? If you're using devise, it should be `current_user`. Btw, if my answer helped you, please upvote and accept my answer(after the time limit).